# What is an overview of Christian views on alien appearances and abductions?

Tags: comparative-christianity, extra-terrestrial-life

[Alien abductions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_abduction), [close encounters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close_encounter) and [UFO sightings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_reported_UFO_sightings) have been widely reported by many individuals around the world. Many self-proclaimed alien abductees and first-hand eyewitnesses of close encounters have testified to this effect. For instance, the YouTube Channel [UFO HUB](https://www.youtube.com/c/UFOHub/videos) hosts multiple interviews with such people. But beyond eyewitness accounts and anecdotes, on a more serious note, the UFO phenomenon in particular has been deemed worthy of a more rigorous evaluation, as evidenced by the [Pentagon UFO videos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagon_UFO_videos) and the [U.S. Intelligence UFO Report](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UFO_Report_(U.S._Intelligence)).

What is an overview of Christian views on alien appearances and abductions? Do most Christian denominations and organizations tend to take an official position on this issue?

Comment: I have heard "Christian" theology positing that the antichrist will be an alien who will bring advanced technologies and thereby deceive the world.  I don't think you deserve the down vote.  There may not be official denominational positions but Christians surely do have opinions and, as usual, there are dangerous ideas being floated. +1

Comment: Hi SRI, My answer was deleted supposedly because it was my opinion as if everyone on the site is not expressing their opinion. Mine was firmly backed by cited scripture. Someone else said it was not an overview, a convoluted unnecessary requirement for a question in itself. The two other answers reported so far are not overviews either. Reporting on a general survey is not an overview. I gave specific examples. I would have to conclude that certain potentially controversial truths are tightly controlled here. Truth is best pursued and discovered in an environment of freedom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What is an overview of Christian views on alien appearances and [abductions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_abduction)?**

Most Christians, do not seem to even believe in aliens, at least not on an official level, so alien appearances and abductions are explained away in other manner of suggestions.

Nevertheless some polls imply the opposite, but nothing on an official level by any denomination:

You will always have individuals in every denomination who are willing to believe in such things. Until there is verifiable scientific sources to prove that aliens exist, the vast majority of Christendom will not even entertain the notion of alien appearances and/or abductions.

> [Religious Americans less likely to believe intelligent life exists on other planets](https://www.pewresearch.org/fact-tank/2021/07/28/religious-americans-less-likely-to-believe-intelligent-life-exists-on-other-planets/)
>
> Religious and secular thinkers alike have long discussed what the implications for religion would be if humans discovered intelligent life on other planets. In the United States, highly religious adults are much more skeptical about the possibility of extraterrestrial life compared with those who are less religious, according to a recent Pew Research Center survey.
>
> This is evidenced by a variety of measures of religious engagement. For example, U.S. Christians are far less likely than religiously unaffiliated Americans to say that their “best guess” is that intelligent life exists on other planets (57% vs. 80%). And U.S. adults who attend religious services on at least a weekly basis are considerably less likely than those who seldom or never attend services to say that intelligent life exists elsewhere (44% vs. 75%).
>
> Similarly, around half of Americans who say religion is very important to them (49%) say their best guess is that intelligent life exists on other planets. By comparison, roughly three-quarters of those who say that religion is less important in their lives (76%) say that intelligent life exists elsewhere. Adults who pray daily are also less likely than those who seldom or never pray to say intelligent life exists on other planets (54% vs. 80%).
>
> White evangelical Protestants, who tend to be highly religious, are less likely than other religious groups to say intelligent life probably exists on other planets; 40% hold this view. Most White non-evangelical Protestants (65%), Catholics (67%) and religiously unaffiliated adults (80%) say their best guess is that there is intelligent life beyond Earth. Black Protestants are more divided on the topic, with 55% saying their best guess is that intelligent life exists on other planets and 44% expressing the opposite opinion. (Due to sample size limitations, this analysis does not show some smaller religious groups, including Jewish and Muslim Americans.)
>
> The June survey also asked Americans whether they believe recent UFO sightings by people in the military are evidence of intelligent life beyond Earth. (The survey was conducted just before the U.S. military’s recent release of a report about UFO sightings.)
>
> Americans who attend religious services weekly or more often are less inclined than others to see military UFO sightings as evidence of extraterrestrial life. This also varies by religious affiliation – though the pattern differs somewhat from the broader question about the existence of life beyond Earth. In fact, while the vast majority of self-described atheists (85%) say their best guess is that intelligent life exists on other planets, far fewer (31%) say that UFOs reported by the military are definitely or probably evidence of this. On this question, atheists are about as skeptical as White evangelical Protestants, 35% of whom see UFOs as evidence of extraterrestrial life.
>
> By contrast, roughly half or more of agnostics (49%), Black Protestants (53%), White non-evangelical Protestants (53%), people who describe their religion as “nothing in particular” (59%) and Catholics (61%) say that UFOs reported by people in the military are definitely or probably evidence that intelligent life exists beyond Earth.
>
> When it comes to whether UFOs are friendly or a threat to U.S. national security, opinions vary modestly along religious lines. Majorities across religious groups say they think UFOs are neither friendly nor unfriendly, and relatively few people – regardless of religion – view UFOs as a major threat to U.S. national security.
>
> [image]

The above poll is simply that and polls may or may not reflect facts. Different polls may have a different outcome depending on different regions or areas of different influences.

[image: Sasquatch]

I hope that the [Sasquatch](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bigfoot) is not in the number of those things considered as aliens. Too many unknowns in this universe already!

Comment: I have no more problem with "life" existing on other planets than I do with it having existed outside the Garden of Eden prior to the Fall. *Sapient* life OTOH would have profound theological implications... (That said, C.S. Lewis seemed to manage all right...)

Comment: `Most Christians, do not seem to even believe in aliens, at least not on an official level, so alien appearances and abductions are explained away in other manner of suggestions.` - It would be helpful if you were to include examples of how Christians explain alien abductee testimonies and similar stories away. For example, are you including here the explanation that they are demonic in nature (see the other answers)?

Comment: Hey Ken, you assert that “Most Christians, do not seem to even believe in aliens”, yet the data you provide indicates otherwise. 51% of protestants and 65% of Catholics say there is intelligent life beyond earth. Even among those who say religion is very important to them, the tally is 49%. For those who pray weekly, it is 64%. These are big increases compared to previous decades. So either people are seeing more convincing evidence or the *Zeitgeist* is preparing the way for more demonic intervention and control in the world (or both).

Comment: Admittedly, these are not pleasant things to contemplate regardless of religious belief. But it is not wise to stick our heads in the sand in the face of mounting evidence along with biblical support for demonic intervention on earth (rulers of darkness and spiritual forces of wickedness Eph 6:12) especially as foretold in Revelation. Chapter 9 sounds like a description of aliens torturing humans.
7 ...and their faces resembled human faces. 8 Their hair was like women’s hair, and their teeth were like lions’ teeth.

Comment: @MartinHemsley Actually I said: **”Most Christians, do not seem to even believe in aliens, *at least not on an official level.*** That said, an official level statement makes a big difference!

Comment: Actually, it's probably more instructive to know what they think privately than what they would admit to officially. Also, the numbers have probably gone up since the Pentagon subsequently released its report on UFOs.

Answer (score 0):

Most of what I have read from the Christian world personally suggest that alien and UFO encounters are either false reports or related to the occult / demonic activity (rather than alien activity). There are Christians who leave open the possibility that aliens may exist but then you have the question of whether or not these aliens have souls and are in need of salvation or whether they are simply not created in God's image.

Jeff Zweerink's book "Is There Life Out There?" ([https://www.amazon.com/There-Life-Out/dp/1886653003](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1886653003)) is a good read on this topic produced by a reputable and fairly well known Christian ministry - Reasons to Believe (https://reasons.org/).

Jeff Zweerink Interview on The Babylon Bee - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=beya_FHe98Q